# variables not read in a string link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to insert a link that contains variables but VScode read my variables as string typed, I tried to install ESLint 3.3.0 to resolve this problem, but it doesn't work, is there any alternative solutions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VMTI.png)

Comment: you can add the variable in the string like this.

'YOUR STRING '+your variable+' '

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using regular quoted strings when you should be using template literals with a backtick (`)

Comment: already solve the prob, i've just seen your solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. VS-code read properly. you need  wrap the string with

```
`text${var}`
```

backtick quotes instead of

```
'text${var}'
```

Comment: Can you send that updated code screen shot

Comment: @ARGOUBadr No screenshot, paste the actual code

Comment: the updates are same as my first screenshot in the question !

Comment: const useGooglSearch = (term) =>  {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() =>
    {
       const fetchData = async() => {
           fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='+API_KEY+'&cx='+CONTEXT_KEY+'&q='+term+''
           )
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(result => {
               setData(result)
           })
       }
       fetchData();
    }, [term])
    return { data }
};

Comment: rest of link..... oogleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='+API_KEY+'&cx='+CONTEXT_KEY+'&q='+term+''

Comment: You haven't made the change suggested... Notice there is a difference between the various quote marks: single (`'`) double (`"`) and backticks (`\``) You need backticks

Comment: @ARGOUBadr please check my answer i have mentioned quotes clearly

Answer (score 0):

use this

`'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='+YOUR VARIABLE+' & cx='+YOUR VARIABLE+' &q='+YOUR VARIABLE+''`

Comment: it is read indeed but the variables are out of the link

Comment: You can add parameters to your fetch function and pass YOUR VARIABLE as params of fetch function.

Comment: It's bad practice to use BASIC style programming, we did this 40 years ago we now have better methods

Comment: 40 years is too much.what is your age now?
Actually ,I am learning the programming.

Comment: @AvirupChakraborty It's certainly worth learning about string concatenation, but as a general rule, if you can use template literals, then you should (The use of `+` to combine strings is one of the most common stumbling blocks for devs who aren't used to JS's loose types, e.g. `"1" + 1 == "11"` is entirely valid, but not exactly intuitive)